# jquery roundabout("getChildInFocus") return false;

Tags: jquery, jquery-roundabout

I am trying to get current child in focus in roundabout, but it returns false. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(".carousel").roundabout({btnNext: ".next",  btnNext: ".next", 
      btnPrev: ".prev", duration: 500 ,});  
    $("#btnPrev").click(function(e){
        $(".carousel").roundabout("animateToNextChild")      
        alert($("UL.carousel").roundabout("getChildInFocus"));
    $("#text").html("HI");
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is my html:

```
<pre>
<div class="container" ><ul class="carousel">
  <li id="1">Pajan</li>
  <li id="2">Behroz</li>
  <li id="3">Mahram</li>
  <li id="4">Delpazir</li>
  <li id="5">Yeko Yek</li>
  <li id="6">Kaleh</li>
  <li id="7" >Tak Daneh</li>
</ul></div>
</pre>
```

I tried a white, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/9H6tF/2/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').roundabout({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        btnNextCallback:function(){
            var what=$('li.roundabout-in-focus').text()
            alert(what)
            },
        btnPrevCallback:function(){
            var what=$('li.roundabout-in-focus').text()
            alert(what)
            }   

        }); 

  });
</script>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.